# Yii2 send message (or notification) to admin after any user make create or update

Tags: yii2

Three weeks ago I was trying to find a way to send message (or notification) to admin after any user make create or update, but ended up with nothing. I searched a lot and I did not find a clear solution, I am trying to understand Yii2 events, I found this link 
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/329/real-time-display-of-server-push-data-using-server-sent-events-sse/

I think it is the key to solve my problem, but I am really stuck I don't know what to do, hope anyone can help me.

thanks

Comment: You could use Yii::trace method to send notifications, put inside the method to trace. Check documentation that explains with example as you have to do. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually I am not Yii2 expert and I am not good with using documentation, I use "Yii2 basic template", if you can tell me step by step what I need to do, when user insert new record or update, I want to send a message or notification with (user name and the sql statment) to the admin. 
thanks again for your time

Comment: If you're not familiar with logging, you can also use your custom queries that represent logging after user registration.

Comment: thanks @EdvinTenovimas if you can give me an example code

Comment: thanks @EdvinTenovimas

Comment: sorry my friend @EdvinTenovimas, I understood you but I didnt get time to contact you, I well do, thanks for your care

Comment: I sent you email :)

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow since it's late now. :)

Answer (score 6):

Consider using a [behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html) to handle this.

**Assumptions**

- You have at least one [model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html) (possibly multiple) within your project.
- You have a [controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html) that contains at least two actions: actionCreate and actionUpdate.
- An email is sent to an administrator whenever either of the aforementioned actions are called.

**Events and Behaviours**

When actionCreate is called a new record is inserted into the database through an instance of a model class that extends [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html). Similarly, when actionUpdate is called an existing record is fetched from the database, updated and saved back. An [event](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html) (i.e: insert or update) is fired by the model (since model extends component and components are responsible for implementing events) on both of these occasions. Yii2 provides the ability to respond to these events using behaviours which "customize the normal code execution of the component”.

In short, this means you can **bind custom code to any given event such that your code executes when the event is fired**.

**Proposed Solution**

Now that we know a little something about events and behaviours, we could create a behaviour that executes some custom code whenever an insert or an update event is fired. This custom code could check the name of the action being called (is it called create or update?) in order to determine whether an email is required to be sent out.

The behaviour is useless on it’s own though, we would need to attach it to any models that should be triggering it.

**Implementation of Solution**

NotificationBehavior.php

```
<?php

namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class NotificationBehavior extends Behavior
{

  /**
   * Binds functions 'afterInsert' and 'afterUpdate' to their respective events.
   */
  public function events()
  {
    return [
      ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_INSERT => 'afterInsert',
      ActiveRecord::EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE => 'afterUpdate',
    ];
  }

  /**
   * This function will be executed when an EVENT_AFTER_INSERT is fired
   */
  public function afterInsert($event)
  {
    // check the 'id' (name) of the action
    if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'create') {
      // send email to administrator 'user performed insert'
    }
  }

  /**
   * This function will be executed when an EVENT_AFTER_UPDATE is fired
   */
  public function afterUpdate($event)
  {
    if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'update') {
      // send email to administrator 'user performed update'
    }
  }

}
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Post;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Creates a new record
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Post;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing record
     */
    public function actionUpdate()
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Post.php (model)

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use app\components\NotificationBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Post extends ActiveRecord
{
  /**
   * specify any behaviours that should be tied to this model.
   */
  public function behaviors()
  {
      return [
          // anonymous behavior, behavior class name only
          NotificationBehavior::className(),
      ];
  }
}
```

I would also advise checking out [Yii2's TimestampBehavior implementation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html#using-timestamp-behavior) for a more concrete example.

Comment: thanks a lot , actually I have 3 models I generated them by Gii, I will try your way, but where I should put NotificationBehavior.php file

Comment: I would probably create a new folder called components: app/components. If you're ever confused about where a file is saved, take a look at the top of the file for a namespace, in most instances this will provide the folder in which the framework expects the class to be declared.

Comment: Hey @Jonathon Dilworth your way works for me, thanks a lot. I save the logs in a table called "logging" but I have a problem, How can I pass the name of model and Controller parameters.

if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'create') {
        $logging = new Logging();
        $logging->created_by = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $logging->log_type = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
        $logging->log_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $logging->log_info = 'Here I want to save the controller Parameters';
        $logging->save();
    }

Comment: If this answer has been helpful, you can always up vote it or mark it as the accepted answer. Yii provides the ability to access the component that the behavior is attached to through the yii\base\Behavior::$owner property (see: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-behaviors.html). This means you can obtain the name of the model that triggered the behaviour by calling: get_class($this->owner); - furthermore, you can access the parameters using: $this->owner->attributes; Note that these will be an array, so you may want to serialize: serialize($this->owner->attributes);

Comment: thanks very much @Jonathon Dilworth your answers very helpful and direct to solution, your answer deserve to upvote but I still not have enough "Reputation", soon I will upvote your answer, you saved me thanks a lot my  friend.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a [model](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html) to "user"? If yes, then just override method afterSave (it fires exactly after making any changes in the model) like this:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

        // your notification logic here

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: yes I have a  module for user, thanks for your comment